# Sharp Input file is missing but path exists

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sharp

I'm trying to use Sharp to compress an image on Google Cloud bucket.
I do:

```
function resize(file: string, size: number) {
  return sharp(file)
    .rotate()
    .resize(size, size, {
      fit: 'inside',
      withoutEnlargement: true,
    })
    .toBuffer();
}
const myFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
console.log('myFile', myFile); // This outputs something like /var/folders/50/xxxxxxxx/T/users/xxxxxxxxx/images/1620673417248.jpg
const modifiedImageBuffer = await resize(myFile, size);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is `myFile` does not actually exist?

Comment: Oh, good point. I'll need to check that.